# Google Maps V3--map doesn't load in IE--loads on refresh

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm very close to completing this map, but it's 2 steps forward 1 step back.  Now that I'm basically done, with help from this forum, IE (8 or 9) isn't loading the map on initial visit to the page: http://www.wrh.noaa.gov/mfr/rec/v2/
I have to refresh the page, and then the map and sidebar displays.  I tried the settimeout on line 599, but have commented it out.  The settimeout did force IE to load the map, but then I got an *el* not defined type of error.

Any ideas how I can get this map to load in IE as well as the currently functional FF and Chrome?

Thanks for any help,
Shad